# Unsatisfied dependencies for type X with qualifiers @Default at injection point (when injecting a EJB session bean)

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

I have an application that is started with ServletContextListener. This weblistener injects a callable object, and calls the call method, it is simplified for this example.

```java
@WebListener
public class StartupServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

  @Inject
  Instance<MasterModule> masterModules;

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
      //Have a future object with the MasterModule
      MasterModule m = masterModules.get();
      try {
          m.call();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
  }  
}
```

The masterModule calls on a process method for another injected object as seen bellow. In this process object i try to access some business logic through a session bean.

```java
public class MasterModule implements Callable<String> {

  @Inject
  private TestModuleI test;

  @Override
  public String call() throws Exception {
      test.process();
      return "";
  }
}
```

In the process method, in TestModule, i try to access some business logic through in a session bean.

```java
public interface TestModuleI {
  void process();
}
```

```java
public class TestModuleImp implements TestModuleI {

  @EJB
  SampleSession sessionBean;

  @Override
  public void process() {
      sessionBean.foo();
  }
}
```

The samplesession bean is currently just a plain sessionbean for testing. 
My problem is that when i try to inject the EJB in TestModuleImp, i get the deployment error written in the SO title. I am able to inject the EJB from the servletContextListener though. My beans.xml has bean-discovery-mode=all

Comment: How about the deployment structure? Its this all within the same war file? Also, have you tried swapping `@EJB` for `@Inject`?

Comment: the weblistener class is wrapped in a war, while the Modules are in a jar packaging and the session beans are in a ejb packaging and archieved with ejb-jar.

Comment: That sounds like the infamous EAR archive visibility trouble. So the Modules, are a separate JAR - where is this jar located?I think your EJB jar needs to declare dependency on the Modules JAR in order for this to work.

Comment: You were indeed right that the main problem were visibility of the modules. I solved it by adding the jar package where i have my testModule in the parent pom as an ejb module:
<ejbModule>
<groupId>X</groupId>
<artifactId>Y<artifactId>
</ejbModul>
This made the artifact visibel for the session beans in the ear package

Comment: Glad I could help :)